# nginx configuration issue to serve on a path

Tags: nginx

I'm having an issue with an nginx local server where I'm doing some test, I need to deploy two different apps into one server, of course I will have to directories from where I'm going to serve both apps:

- html/first
- html/second

This is my conf file:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  dev.example.com;
        index        index.html;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root      html/first;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /second {
            alias     html/second;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}
```

The error I'm seeing is that when I hit the url: `dev.example.com` it loads the page in the folder `html/first` and that's correct, if I hit the url: `dev.example.com/second` it shows me the page in the folder `html/second` but when I hit `dev.example.com/second/dashboard` (this is a single page app) the server should continue to serve the index.html file in `html/second` folder but instead ins showing me again the content in the `html/first`.

Can someone bring me some lights on how to solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with this configuration:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  dev.example.com;
        index        index.html;


        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;


    location / {
            alias html/first/;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;
    }

    location /second {
            alias html/second/;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ index.html =404;
    }
}
```

No if I hit the url: http://dev.example.com/ it will serve the index.html file in the `first` and if I hit http://dev.example.com/second/ or http://dev.example.com/second/dashboard etc. it will point to `second`